# basic question flatness and non-zero divisors: $B/fB$ flat implies $f$ is a non-zero divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A \to B$ be a ring homomorphism of (Noetherian) rings. Let $f \in B$, and suppose that $B/fB$ is flat over $A$. Something I'm reading says then that $f$ is a non-zero divisor. Why?

Edit: as pointed out by Pedro T. in the comments, the statement is not true.

Comment: If $A=k$ is a field then the flatness condition is always trivially satisfied, but many $k$-algebras have zero divisors.